# Minimum distance from receptacle terminal to conduit connector

Tags: electrical, receptacle, conduit

Is there a minimum distance required from a receptacle terminal to a conduit connector?  Surely this is defined in the NEC somewhere right? [image]

Comment: I think the arcing distance for 120v is less than a thousandth of an inch, but this is an interesting question.

Comment: I think how you have it installed now looks fine, but if the screws slightly loosened and the receptacle slid as far right as those oval holes allow, would it be touching the conduit?  Because that can easily happen at some point down the road.

Comment: That's under ideal conditions @JPhi1618. Add some condensation and all bets are off.

Comment: It will never fit a GFCI. That's why I only tap off the top or bottom of a box, ideally using the center knockout (and if it's out the back, and not a deep box, *always* in the center). That's why imo this fails "workmanlike manner". It's not a pull box, it's a device location, some types of which will no longer fit.

Comment: If you're going to surface mount a single gang outlet box (just don't? ... or), get a deep one because they don't make single gang surface mount coverplates, either of which would make this a non-issue (deeper, or 2-gang box with a proper coverplate). I see how it's already completely biased to the other side... I don't like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in NEC 110.12. Mechanical Execution of Work. "Electrical equipment shall be installed in a neat and workmanlike manner."  (which does not mean nipping back all the wires in your service panel).

First, they make non-metallic caps for the ends of conduit fittings. Google "rigid conduit insulated bushing". They are nominally to prevent wire gouging, but they will solve this nicely.

[image]

Second, run those screws down all the way, then wrap the receptacle with electrical tape.  No reason to leave screws exposed.

Speaking of neat, you have a metal junction box where the receptacle yoke is landing hard flush on the box.  Get rid of the little paper squares on the mounting screws, and you'll have a valid grounding path and won't need a ground wire to the receptacle.

You don't need a ground wire in the pipe, but if you have one, it needs to go to the ground screw on the metal junction box.  Going to the receptacle is not enough because the ground would be disconnected if the receptacle is removed.

If this is outdoors or if the pipe is subject to physical damage, there's wisdom in running ground wires also.

Comment: can you please clarify the "non-metallic caps for the ends of conduit fittings".